# How can I fill missing data points in R for a given dataframe

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a dataframe which contains dates, products and amounts.  However product b is not on every date, I would like it to be with an NA or 0 balance.  Is this possible?

```
Summary_Date <- 
  as.Date(c("2017-01-31",
        "2017-02-28",
        "2017-03-31",
        "2017-03-31",
        "2017-04-30",
        "2017-05-31",
        "2017-05-31",
        "2017-06-30"))
Product <-
  as.character(c("a","a","a","b","a","a","b","a"))
Amounts <-
  as.numeric(c(10,10,10,20,10,10,20,10))

df <- data.frame(Summary_Date,Product,Amounts)
```

Regards,
Aksel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **tidyr**:

```
> library(tidyr)
> complete(data = df,Summary_Date,Product)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Summary_Date Product Amounts
         <date>  <fctr>   <dbl>
 1   2017-01-31       a      10
 2   2017-01-31       b      NA
 3   2017-02-28       a      10
 4   2017-02-28       b      NA
 5   2017-03-31       a      10
 6   2017-03-31       b      20
 7   2017-04-30       a      10
 8   2017-04-30       b      NA
 9   2017-05-31       a      10
10   2017-05-31       b      20
11   2017-06-30       a      10
12   2017-06-30       b      NA
```

Comment: @AkselEtingu Sounds like you specified the arguments incorrectly (i.e. called complete with the first argument being a date vector instead of a data frame). But it's impossible to say for sure without seeing a complete example.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help;  This is the dataframe structure I have: Summary_Date as Date, Segment as chr, Event as chr, HL_Group as chr, HL_Sub_Group as chr and vlaue as num.  I have complete(Data = Debt_Flow, Debt_Flow$Summary_Date, Debt_Flow$Event)  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @AkselEtingu In my example, did I refer to the data frame columns with the `Debt_Flow$` prefix? I think I did not. I can't help any more in comments. If you have a second problem, ask a question with a complete, reproducible example.